# Tomcat on external server

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I have an external server (ubuntu) running an instance of tomcat and I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to make it accessible via the server domain name as opposed to just the IP address.

So at the moment this currently works :

```
http://12.34.56.78:8080/MyApp
```

However what I need is to make my tomcat instance accessible using the following :

```
http://my-domain.com:8080/MyApp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know what is a dns? have you registered a domain? it seems like your question is just to broad, and is on verge of explaining basically how the internet works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a DNS entry for your domain name. The entry must point to the ip of the server.
Is your domain already registered?